# Order by desc seems to fail

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So i own a online game and each user has a trainer level so we can rank them highest to lowest. In the database there trainer level are stored has one number so example 1 or 4 or 5. We then divide that by 0.001 to get there true trainer level.

Here is what ive coded so far.

```
$pageLimit=PAGE_PER_NO*$id;
$query="SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY trainer_level DESC limit $pageLimit,".PAGE_PER_NO;
$res=mysql_query($query);
$count=mysql_num_rows($res);
$HTML='';
if($count > 0){


    echo "<table width='100%' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>"; 
echo "<table width='100%' border='1' table class='gridtable' >


<tr>
<th>Username</th>
<th>Trainer Level</th>

</tr>";

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
        {
        $i++;

        echo '<td><img src="http://domainame.com/'.$row['avatar'].'" border=0>' ;
        echo "<a href='membersprofile.php?nicky=".$row['username']." '>" . $row['username'] . "</a></td>";


    echo "<td>";
    echo "Wins:     ";
    $trainer_level= mysql_real_escape_string($row['trainer_level']);
$trainer_level2 = strip_tags($trainer_level);

$b = '0.001';

$total = ($trainer_level2 * $b)  ;
      echo $total ;
      "</td>";

  echo "</tr>";

        }
         echo "</table>"; 


}else{
  $HTML='No Data Found';
}
echo $HTML;
```

Here is a screen shot of what i get
http://gyazo.com/994d215f0621371c62d9d1c087f77b1f.png

Has you can see 0.008 is higher up than Wins: 0.075
but 0.075 is greater than 0.008

Comment: Select CAST(trainer_level AS DECIMAL(30,3)) as tl from table order by tl desc  your value is translated as a string, not decimal

Comment: By the way, mixing your logic and your presentation like this will only lead to headache further down the road. If you can separate your PHP from your HTML - possibly by using an MVC framework - your site will be a lot easier to maintain!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is because your `trainer_level` column is not a numeric data type. You need to convert it into a number before sorting.

Comment: Thank you this worked how silly of me it was var when it should of been int